# Is it possible to send HTML as a reponse of a WebService call?

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

Since the format of the response of a web service request seems to be Xml or Json. But, since HMTL is a kindOf XML, I wonder if it possible (and common practice) to send HTML back to client...

Comment: it depends what you need this html for in the client. Surely you can return a string and that string can contain anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a general practice to return HTML, but you can return HTML by enclosing it inside a string in JSon or XML

You can do:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetHTMLString()
{
    return "<HTML><TITLE>...";
}
```

Found this on [return html from wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019708/return-html-from-wcf-service)

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public Stream getHtml()
{
    // get the html
    var html = DoSomethingToGetHtml();  //Not a built-in .Net method ;)

    // we want our result interpreted as plain html
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";

    // create a stream from our html because trying to return a string adds an extra header tag
    //      to the response.  Returning a stream returns the html by itself
    var result = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));

    // return the result
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send xml response to client and inside embed html code. Its not a common practice to send html but it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can either return HTML directly and interpret the result as such on the client or you can wrap HTML in a result object that would then be either SOAP or JSON encoded by your web service framework.