# Wcf Rest Service + UI in html Page

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a WCF Service which shares some data via REST. Now, instead of a JSON format I want to have some UI for it - Html page. I don't want to have separate WCF Service and Web page, I want to have it integrated.

To summarize:
I want to have UI (Web page) for my WCF rest Service but I dont want to host it as another module. What is the best approach to do this?

EDIT:

My approach is to have MainPage method in WCFService which returns html that contains jquery queries to another informations from WCFService. Is it good idea?

```
  public Stream GetMainPage()
        {
            var str = @"../index.html";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

first add an [wcf http endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178(v=vs.110).aspx), if you not already have,

then I would read the file Content of the index.html maybe with System.IO.File.ReadAllText

and send it as html [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019708/return-html-from-wcf-service)

Comment: yes thanks, but I am asking generally about convention. Not the specified code presented in first post